# Brotli not compressing for small bodies

Tags: node.js, server, compression, brotli

I am trying to compress a small HTTP response with the data of [].

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 30 Mar 2023 15:50:03 GMT
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

2
[]
0
```

However, after sending the compressed Brotli to the browser, it simply hangs as if it is still parsing the data. I was wondering if there was an issue with Brotli compressing small data? It works for larger amounts of data.

Here is the code that I coded in NodeJS to compress the data body:

```js
import zlib from 'node:zlib';

const compressedBody = await new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
    zlib.brotliCompress(body, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            process.stderr.write('Error occured while brotli compressing');
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is that the HTTP response that you show us? What's the 2 and the 0? And why is there no `Content-Encoding: br`?

Comment: The data shown is the http response from the server. The 2 and 0 are chuncked encoding lengths.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I am trying to compress this response after the fact with Brotli, so given this data [] I am then trying to compress this to Brotli and send it to the browser client

Answer (score 0):

Compression of (requests and) responses in HTTP/1.1 means compressing only the payload. The headers are not compressed, nor are the chunked encoding lengths. If you compress the entire response (as you seem to have done), the browser does not understand it.

A chunked HTTP/1.1 response with Brotli-compressed `[]` payload looks so:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: br
Date: Thu, 30 Mar 2023 15:50:03 GMT
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

6
��[]
0
```

Note that the "compressed" payload is 6 bytes long whereas the uncompressed payload is only 2 bytes.

Comment: Yes I currently do not compress the headers, I only compress the payload. Another weird thing is I convert the Transfer-Encoding chunked into just a content length of size 6 for simplicity here

Comment: Can you share your code that does the compression?

Comment: I am just using nodejs zlib brotli compress. Do you still want the source code to how I compress it?

Comment: If you want further analysis of your problem, yes.

Comment: Alright I just updated my original statement to include the code that compresses it. I didn't think the code was necessary since the Node internal library properly compresses the body when the size is bigger, like lets say the body is greater than 100, and only doesn't work if the body is small

Comment: Can you share more context of your code? You speak of a Node internal library, which is that? Where do you get the `body` from? And: Where do you set the header `Content-Encoding: br`?

Comment: The body is a Buffer which I am trying to send. The Node internal library is zlib:
import zlib from 'node:zlib';
and I set the header manually which is just a line:   headerArrayWithProperEncoding.push('Content-Encoding: br');

Comment: If it is relevant, this payload is being sent to the browser since I am simply .pipe what webpack sends to me and sending it over to the browser to build the web page